# Get contact name from just the number

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cursor, contacts

Say i have an edit text and a button. In the edit text you would type a number and then when you hit the button it will either show the contact information or return with the name of that contact.

I have tried all sorts of methods provided with no luck. The one i have successfully gotten the furthest with was the following... But i had no luck returning the name.

```
Cursor phoneCursor = null;
    contactList = new HashMap<String,String>();

  try{
       Uri uContactsUri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;

      String strProjection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME;

      phoneCursor = getContentResolver().query(uContactsUri, null, null, null, strProjection);
      phoneCursor.moveToFirst();

      String name = "";
      String phoneNumber = "";

       int nameColumn = phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
       int phoneColumn = phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);



           phoneCursor.moveToNext();

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("[SmsMain] getContactData", e.toString());
    }
    finally{
       if(phoneCursor != null){
          phoneCursor.close();
          phoneCursor = null;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below method to get contact name and if number doesnot exist the instead of name the same number is returned.

```
private String getContactNameFromNumber(String number) {
        // define the columns I want the query to return
        String[] projection = new String[] {
                Contacts.Phones.DISPLAY_NAME,
                Contacts.Phones.NUMBER };

        // encode the phone number and build the filter URI
        Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_FILTER_URL, Uri.encode(number));

        // query time
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null,
                null, null);

        // if the query returns 1 or more results
        // return the first result
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            String name = c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(Contacts.Phones.DISPLAY_NAME));
            return name;
        }

        // return the original number if no match was found
        return number;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to use the optimized PhoneLookup provider as described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.html)

Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
Cursor cursor = resolver.query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME},null,null,null);

Refer this [LINK](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/) for more Details